# If Hive support column statistics about histogram？

Tags: hive, statistics

I got information about Hive column statistics from doc[image: doc] and code[image: code], but when i try got column statistics, i can not find field histogram. What's the reason for this, my Hive version is 3.1.0.[image: hive]

On hive client side, create table and execute anaylze, but no field histogram? Is problem about Hive version or data type or just not support now？